# How to reload users.txt of JProfiler licence server without restart?

Tags: jprofiler

Is there any way to reload the ejtserver (JProfiler license server) configuration, particularly users.txt, without losing all active connections?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to do that. I've added it to our issue tracker.